# Registrar Usuarios en php Poo

Tags: php, html, poo

Estoy retomando php y estoy haciendo un ejercicio donde quiero registrar un usuario con html y php usando poo, pero no me acuerdo como era para hacerlo desde un formulario, así es como lo tengo pero no funciona.

```
<?php
        include ("functions.php");
        $obj = new Nucleo();
        echo $obj->registro;
    ?>
    <form action="functions.php" method="post">
        <hr />
        <h3>Crea una cuenta</h3>
        <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" maxlength="32" required>
        <br/><br/>
        <label for="pass">Apellido:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="apellido" maxlength="8" required>
        <br/><br/>
        <label for="pass">Telefono:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="telefono" maxlength="8" required>
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Registrar">
    </form>
```

mi archivo de functions

```
class Nucleo{

    public function registro(){

        include ("conexion.php");

        $nombre   = $_POST['nombre'];
        $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
        $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pw, $db);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

        $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (Nombre, Apellido, Telefono)
        VALUES ('$_POST[nombre]', '$_POST[apellido]', '$_POST[telefono]')";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

            echo '<script>jQuery(function(){   
                swal({
                    title: "¡Datos Guardados!",
                    text: "Presiona OK para continuar",
                    type: "success",
                }, 
                function(){
                    window.location.href = "usuarios.html";
                })
            });</script>';

        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

    }
}
```

el archivo conexion.php es donde esta lo especificado de server y base datos.

agradecería una pista de como se hace, deje de practicar php y se olvido, y buscando en la web no me aparece lo que quiero.

gracias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba  con las comillas al llamar a 
$_POST osea `$_POST["nombre"]`, entonces prueba.

```php
     $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (Nombre, Apellido, Telefono)
      VALUES ('".$_POST["nombre"]."', '".$_POST["apellido"]."', '".$_POST["telefono"]."')";
```

Después en un archivo llamado `nucleo.php` pones la clase nucleo.
Después en un archivo llamado ejemplo  `registro.php` llamas a núcleo y le pasas el $_post y la conexion si quieres.

```php
   //... registro.php
   include('conexion.php')
   include('nucleo.php')
   $nucleo  = new Nucleo();
   $conexion = new mysqli($host, $user, $pw, $db); // opcional..
   $message = $nucle->registro($_POST, $conexion);

   // opcion 1: mostrar el formulario en la url /registro.php
   include('formulario.php')

   // opcion 2: redireccionar a formulario.php
   // header("Location: http://www.example.com/blog");
   // exit;
```

```php
   <?php
   $how_message = false;
   if(isset($message){
     $message = ""
   }
   ?>
   <!-- FORMULARIO -->
   <form action="registro.php">
     ....
   </form>
   <!-- MENSAJE -->
    <?php 
    if($how_message == true) { ?>
      <span> <?= $message ?> </span>
    <?php } //end if ?>
```

Comment: creo que no me entendiste, lo que quiero es llamar el metodo desde el html para registrar el usuario, el insert esta bien

Comment: Hola @DANIELFERNANDOSALINAS, la propiedad action debe apuntar hacia el archivo que realizara el función de registro, y luego regresa al formulario o pantalla de registro exitoso.  Actualizara la respuesta me informas que tal.

Comment: Viendo un poco mas el código probablemente el error se deba a que no estas usando los paracentesis al llamar el método registro. `echo $obj->registro;` debería ser así `echo $obj->registro();` ademas php es un lenguaje interpretado el código de la clase núcleo debería estar antes de su implementación.